# Is it impossible for Earth Stargate be modded to dial all Stargates?

Tags: stargate, stargate-sg1, stargate-atlantis, stargate-universe

Are there any *Stargate* episodes (*SG-1*, *Atlantis*, *Universe*) that hints/imply that Carter **cannot** modify the Earth gate to dial all of the Stargates in the Milky Way Galaxy, the same way as the gate at Dakara did in ["Reckoning, Part II"](https://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/Reckoning,_Part_2_(episode))?

Sam has a cable running from laptop to Dakara device in order to interface with it. Obviously the stargate on Dakara can also be controlled from the Dakara device.

[image: Sam looking at her computer]

From [this transcript](https://www.gateworld.net/sg1/s8/transcripts/817.shtml)

> JACOB: I'm not getting anything. (He steps aside and lets Sam have a go.)
>
> CARTER (as she starts to type): This may not be possible, y'know.
>
> JACOB: C'mon, Sam -- it can't be any harder than blowing up a sun.
>
> (Sam looks irritated.)
>
> CARTER: Y'know, you blow up one sun and suddenly everyone expects you to walk on water!
>
> (At that moment, the interface between the laptop and the Ancient screen begins to work.)

[image: interface activates]

Jacob pushes the console on the Dakara device, activates device and stargate:

> (Jacob is concentrating on the laptop as the readout finally drops to 0.76 and the message "Margin achieved" appears on the screen.)
>
> JACOB: Point 76!
>
> CARTER: Do it!
>
> (Jacob slams his fist down onto the button on the console that will activate the weapon. The temple begins to shake.)
>
> Up above the temple, a tall statue-like structure peels open like the petals of a flower. Near the Replicator ship in the temple grounds, the Stargate kawhooshes.

Sam can use her computer interface to **reprogram the gate** at Dakara from the dakara wave device.

> ... BAAL: You want me to reprogramme the Stargate to dial every Gate in the galaxy simultaneously.
>
> CARTER: I know you used the Gates' automatic update programme to disseminate a dialling programme virus to the entire Gate network.
>
> BAAL: With a virus you initially planted in my Stargate.
>
> CARTER: No-one's trying to deny that we're mortal enemies here. Can you do it or not?
>
> BAAL: I cannot believe I'm even considering co-operating with a female of the Tau'ri ... (he looks at Jacob) and a Tok'Ra.
>
> SELMAK: This was not my idea, believe me.
>
> BAAL: I'll instruct my troops to land.
>
> CARTER: No way. You send one Jaffa down here and the deal's off.
>
> BAAL: I cannot do what you ask by means of a hologram transmission.
>
> CARTER: Sure you can. Just tell me what to do.

Kindly comment if you find something wrong with the logic or if you can remember any *Stargate* episode (*SG-1*, *Atlantis*, *Universe*) that says or hints or implies that they dont have the knowledge (software) to reprogram.

Comment: I'm not sure this episode says much on it one way or the other. I'd suspect Ba'al didn't do anything but look up the command in the Dakara device. Recall it was the device used to restore life to the Galaxy after the ancient's plague. Therefore it *needed* multi-dial to do it. The only other time we see it used was the failed device from "window of opportunity", also an Ancient device meant to address the plague. Kind of neat we see the indirect progression of technology with multidial being used in a totally different way later. Ba'al true to form just took credit for a built in function.

Answer (score 6):

To my knowledge, no (it's possible I'm wrong), the closest we come from Stargate command is the dialling program for the Milky Way - Pegasus bridge.

The ability to dial every gate in the galaxy in essence comes from Baal, though it could be argued that the basic work was done at SG-1 when developing the Avenger virus.

Comment: Even the Avenger virus doesn't exactly dial every gate; it's been a while since I watched the episode, but if I remember correctly the virus just affected the coordinate system of a single infected DHD, which spread to the rest of the network through subspace (The "correlative update program", a.k.a. "Not Carter's best technobabble). Regardless I think you're right; I don't remember the SGC ever doing anything like this either

Comment: no The avenger Virus does not, but Baal mentions the virus as a reference to his work when doing the modifications to dial all the gates at once at Dakara

Comment: I clearly need to watch that one again; good memory

Comment: Thanks for the effort guys. I found the justification I need for my fanfic - well sort of (software-wise at least). But at least I can justify the possibility based on canon.
I'm going to edit the the question.

Comment: @Jesterscup and Jason Barker thanks. Your answers pointed me to a possibility for my scenario

Comment: @tls - if Jesterscup's answer helped you, you should mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the checkmark under the vote count :)

Comment: It is also worth noting that Baal is not the one who developed the program to dial them all, and likely the virus update to avenger either. Those was created by Nerus, assuming a Goa'uld would not lie and take credit for someone else's work...

Answer (score 2):

It is possible.

Dialing all of the gates at the same time is just a computer program. During the episode where the Ori are attempting to create the first super gate Nerus comes to planet Earth and boasts that he is the one who created the program to dial all of the gates at the same time. Even if he was lying about creating it Baal himself had no link to the gate or Dakara device during the episode to create it "there" himself.

This means the Dakara device is not needed. Just the program code. That could have been done in a lab or connected to a dhd (similar to searching for the modified avenger code) on a safe planet. And since Earth has their own dialing device it is possible that gate could be used to dial all the gates.

The only reason Sam, did not create the program herself is because she did not have time to. During that time she was fighting replicators and helping to calibrate the Dakara device.

From what we know the only things in the way of Sam (or anyone on Earth) dialing all the gates in the galaxy are two things:

1. Power. We know the incoming gates are supposed to get their power from the dialing gate. Dialing all the gates I assume would require a lot of power.
2. Earth's makeshift DHD program. The DHD is just the computer and phone for the dialing program. Earth has their own they built from scratch. It is possible that our McGyver (haha get it) program is missing some key component of the protocols in the DHD program that would allow it to dial all gates.

Assuming those two factors are not in play it is entirely possible and nothing has ever stated that it can not happen.

Comment: One could argue that Sam also didn't know how to. She's not a god.

Comment: Too true... That is why I believe Nerus when he says he built it... Baal is too much of a playboy!

Comment: @Odin1806 I do believe Baal is smart enough to have created the program himself. He certainly seamed to know more about calibrating the Dakara device than Sam, although he was basically being a a-hole about it.

Comment: haha, maybe... i don't want to inflate anyone's ego though...

Answer (score 0):

The Stargate on Earth lacks a DHD, making it less capable than other gates (dials slower, for example).

The Dakara (T'kara?) gate is no different to any other Milky Way gate (including the one on Earth, if you set aside the matter of the DHD).

Humans wrote the Avenger virus which inspired Ba'al's activities, which in turn served as the basis on which the Dakara gate dialed all the Milky Way gates simultaneously.

If the Earth gate was connected up with a genuine original-equipment DHD (like the Antarctica gate if it was still available, which it wasn't at the time of the Dakara incident), it would surely be as capable of a simultaneous gate-dial as the one on Dakara.

Limited to a human-constructed terrestrial power supply and computer-based "MacGyvered" DHD, a Dakara-style simultaneous gate dial is almost certainly beyond its abilities. But then Samantha Carter can, as her father/Selmak asserts, "walk on water", so anything is possible.